# "Exec format error" with docker run command

Tags: shell, docker, sh, dockerfile

I have this Golang based Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY bin/huru .

CMD ./huru
```

I checked and the huru binary file is in the working dir. I get this error:

> /bin/sh: 1: ./huru: Exec format error

anyone know what that is about? "docker build" succeeds, but "docker run" fails with that error.

Answer (score 9):

The "Exec format error" was simply because I was copying the binary file built on OSX/MacOS into the Docker image and trying to run that binary file in the Linux container. That don't work.

Here is the Dockerfile that worked for me:

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENV GOPATH /app

RUN go install huru

ENTRYPOINT /app/bin/huru
```

and my project structure like so on my host fs:

```
$GOPATH/
      src/
        huru/
      .dockerignore
      Dockerfile
```

I run:

```
docker build -t foo .
docker run foo
```

my .dockerignore file contains:

```
.vscode
bin
pkg
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run the docker image on Macos then just specifying the target OS is sufficient:

Assuming there is a src and bin folder, execute in the src folder:

```
env GOOS=linux go build  -o ../bin
```

(this works with m1, uses the arm64 architecture)

BTW
I would not use latest, I see that there is a docker image based on 1.20 which is not yet officially released at time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your application (`huru`) for the target architecture in MacOS and then copy it into the docker image. To build for the target architecture you have to use command in the following format:
`env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o application main.go`
This has the added advantage of having a clean `dockerfile` and smaller image.